# Is it possible to use Fingerprint SDK with Chromium custom Build?

Tags: sdk, chromium, fingerprint, chromium-embedded

Hi i am new to Chromium Custom Browsers, i wanted to build a Custom browser with Chromium build as well as i wanted to use Fingerprint SDK.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', '.scanFingerprint', function(e){
   var fingerprintID = scanFingerPrint();
   alert('Scanned FingerPrint ID: '+fingerprintID);
});
</script>
```

And i want to call some javascript function from my website and the functions should let me to access the fingerprint readers.

Please let me to know is it possible? if yes how i should start? and what is the flow?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Fingerprint SDKs I came across are meant to run on Desktop and interact directly with USB devices connected to the machine not through browser. I did some research on similar stuff before and was bent on using applets as that if given permission can access client devices. I don't think you will be able to use/access the Fingerprint SDK API from the browser. The option I can think of is to find out the USB type of your scanner and try out the following:
[Chrome USB Devices](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_usb)
and [Another Helpful link on chrome USB](http://www.appnearme.com/blog/2014/7/21/chrome-usb-hid-controlling-your-usb-device-javascr/)

It will be helpful to mention which Fingerprint SDK you are referring to. The other possible solution is to try ActiveX.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. i have seen one of development company they deploy custom chrome browser, in that we can access fingerprint reader, but they give the browser for linux. and i asked how that browser works? they replied they developed the browser with chromium build.